# importing project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Hello I am new to Eclipse (and I am a novice in Java): I am creating a project which should make use of some classes from another project. Do I have to export necessarily this last project as JAR file and add in my project? Are there other alternatives?

Comment: it depends if you have dependencies to another project/JAR/library then you have to add them to the classpath of your project in order to use them. I'd recommend you download maven and build project with it which makes life lot easier then keep track of all dependencies necessary for your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several alternatives:

- If project A depends on project B, and both projects are in the same Eclipse workspace, you can just project B to project A's build path (project properties / build path / project). This has the nice advantage that it will (optionally) automatically pull in project B's JARs, plus updates to B will be used automatically by A, and you can debug into B's code (even using hot code replace).
- If A and B are fairly separate, just make B into a JAR (or several ones), then add these to A's build path.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have the source of those class files you can just link that source
2. Or add the other project as a dependent project.
3. Or create a jar of those classes and add that in lib.